# Conditionally filter grouped sequence of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

In this type of data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:12,
  Sequ = c(1,1,1,1,
           3,3,3,
           5,5,5,
           6,6),
  N_ipu = c(1,0,1,1,
            1,4,1,
            1,1,1,
            5,1)
)
```

I need to remove those `Sequ`ences of contiguous rows that contain in column `N_ipu`values **other than `0` and `1`**. I've tried the below, with little success:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sequ) %>%
  # filter(N_ipu %in% c(1,0))
  # filter(if_all(N_ipu) %in% c(1,0))
  # filter(if_all(N_ipu), ~all(.) %in% c(1,0))
```

Using `dplyr`, how can I subset `df` on those `Sequ` as wholes that contain only `0`and `1`?
The **desired output** is this:

```
   id Sequ N_ipu
1   1    1     1
2   2    1     0
3   3    1     1
4   4    1     1
8   8    5     1
9   9    5     1
10 10    5     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `any` to remove all element of the group, and `!` to invert the selection.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Sequ) %>% 
  filter(!any(N_ipu > 1))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Sequ [2]
     id  Sequ N_ipu
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     2     1     0
3     3     1     1
4     4     1     1
5     8     5     1
6     9     5     1
7    10     5     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sequ) %>%
   filter(all(N_ipu %in% c(1,0)))
```

---

```
     id  Sequ N_ipu
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     2     1     0
3     3     1     1
4     4     1     1
5     8     5     1
6     9     5     1
7    10     5     1
```